# Forcing Vue to re-render elements with removed attributes

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom

In my Vue project I use a third party library that's not set up to integrate particularly well with Vue, as it performs manual DOM manipulation, for example by removing the "disabled" attribute of an element that's to be conditionally disabled. Whenever this library performs these operations I want Vue to refresh its state. At first glance the `$forceUpdate` method seemed perfect, but it doesn't seem to be working as I'd expect... [Here's](https://codepen.io/calbro/pen/yLYwyvX) a Codepen demonstrating things, after the call to `removeAttribute` I need some way of making Vue start applying the conditional "disabled" tag again.

The code:

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    buttonDisabled: true,
  }
});

document.getElementById('button').removeAttribute('disabled');

vm.$forceUpdate(); // doesn't work
```

and

```
<div id="app">
  <button id="button" :disabled="buttonDisabled">
    test
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should treat your templates as "pure functions", meaning you shouldn't interfere with the rendered output, otherwise you would get unexpected results due to such side effects.

Vue skips re-rendering because nothing has changed, so you need to make changes so it properly re-renders.

In your specific example, you can do that by toggling the `disabled` prop using `$nextTick`.

```js
document.getElementById('button').removeAttribute('disabled');

// first change
vm.buttonDisabled = false;

// wait until the update queue is done so Vue can pick up the changes
vm.$nextTick(() => {
  // toggle it back on
  vm.buttonDisabled = true;
})
```